# How to load .model and .emb files generated from Node2Vec embeddings in python?

Tags: machine-learning, graph, networkx, word2vec, embedding

I have created node embeddings using Node2Vec. I have saved the model and the node embeddings using the following code-

```
EMBEDDING_FILENAME = './embeddings.emb'
EMBEDDING_MODEL_FILENAME = './embeddings.model'

# Save embeddings for later use
model.wv.save_word2vec_format(EMBEDDING_FILENAME)

# Save model for later use
model.save(EMBEDDING_MODEL_FILENAME)
```

I want to use these saved model `.model` and `.emb` files to create edge embeddings.

How can I load these files/model/node embeddings?

Answer (score 2):

As stated in [this answer](https://github.com/eliorc/node2vec/issues/20) from the Node2Vec library's author,

> the `Node2Vec.fit` method returns an instance of `gensim.models.Word2Vec`, you can see [in the documentation](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html) how to save and load a model.

There are two options, depending on how you stored your model. See below a snippet for doing that:

```
from gensim.models import Word2Vec

# Load model after Node2Vec.save
model = Word2Vec.load(PATH_TO_YOUR_SAVED_MODEL)

# Load model after Node2Vec.wv.save_word2vec_format
model = Word2Vec.wv.load_word2vec_format(PATH_TO_YOUR_SAVED_WORD2VEC_FORMAT)
```

Note that calling the `Word2Vec.load` method with `(fname=PATH_TO_YOUR_SAVED_MODEL)` (as in the documentation) raises an error, because apparently the right parameter name is `fname_or_handle` as for `Word2Vec.save`.